# Could not load file or assembly 'EPiServer.Framework'

Tags: asp.net, iis, upgrade, episerver

Im getting this exception when configuring EPi CMS 5 to run under IIS7.5.

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'EPiServer.Framework' or one of its dependencies.
>
> Source Error: 
>        An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>        Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'EPiServer.Framework' could not be loaded.
>
> ```
>  WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
> ```
>
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>        Stack Trace:
>
> ```
>  [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EPiServer.Framework' or one of its dependencies. Det går inte att
> ```
>
> hitta filen.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name,
>   Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +95
>   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +54    System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +69
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +52
>        [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'EPiServer.Framework' or one of its dependencies. Det går inte att
>   hitta filen.]    System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement,
>   XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +360
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean
>   checkAptcaBit) +27
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +44
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +52
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList) +200
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
>   +1365    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +95
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +339
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +253
>        [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'EPiServer.Framework' or one of its dependencies. Det går inte att
>   hitta filen.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +9080108
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +256

Answer (score 1):

Check the /Bin folder of your application and see if the EPiServer.Framework DLL is there. If it isn't you can set the DLL to "Copy Local" by right clicking on it in the References folder within Solution Explorer and selecting Properties, then set Copy Local to "true". Now when you build the solution, the DLL will be copied from it's reference location into the Bin folder. You may need to do this for all the EPiServer DLLs.

I've experienced this in the past and even when "Specific Version" is enabled there are still issue loading the correct DLLs. One way we solved it was to copy all the EPiServer DLLs into a Lib folder in our solution directory and add the references to those DLLs, keeping Specific Version and Copy Local set to true.

Comment: I dont think there is supposed to be a separate Episerver.Framework.DLL. Ive checked with other working versions of the same CMS.

Comment: @Lautaro Well, why is your application trying to load one? [EPiServer.Framework was released with CMS 6](http://world.episerver.com/Articles/Items/Introducing-EPiServer-Framework/), are you sure you're referencing the CMS 5 DLLs? Try setting "Specific version" to true for the DLLs in the properties window.

Comment: Good point! I have sett Specific Version to true for all Epi DLLs, but the result is the same. I have checked the Assembly bindings in the web.config and they are all sett to newVersion="5.2.375.236".